# Vba Excel Saving embedded OLE object

Tags: excel, vba, ole

i have lot of workbooks wich have embedded objets (images,pdf and zip files) and i need to exctract those files to hard disk.
I have found this code:

```
Sub Test()
 'copy oleobject
 ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Objeto 3").Copy
 'paste to activeworkbook's path
 CreateObject("Shell.Application") _
 .Namespace(ActiveWorkbook.Path) _
 .Self.InvokeVerb "Paste"
End Sub
```

but the problem is that y get a file whiout extension.

I need get the name of the object that appears in this image

[image]

but i dont found a method to get those names.

Someone can i help me?.

Comment: The method above should give the pasted object its name with extension. At least for me.

Comment: It does not work for me, maybe because objects do not have a link.